# How to share an allure report over email

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest, allure

I have developed an automation framework using Selenium and pytest. Allure is the reporting tool used in the framework.
Can anyone please help me to know how an allure report can be shared?
Are there any better reporting tools available for pytest?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Its not related to any quality related stuff of the application and sharing report over an email is mostly depends on self env and organisational practices

Answer (score 1):

You can use your build tools to save the generated report on the cloud, allowing you to share a link.

E.g. this [Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/allure-jenkins-plugin/) enables you to save the report as an artefact. Then you can simply give the artefact/job link to whomever wants to look.

Comment: Thanks @Farias. Follow up, would you be able to advise how one can share, from Jenkins to Slack, the link you mention?

Comment: @TinasheChinyanga If the answer is satisfiable, could you mark it as accepted? It helps others to know it is what you were looking for. For your question, you can take a look at this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-slack-integration